# SQL Yes/No query without control flow functions (IF,CASE,COALESCE etc)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've been trying to find a way to get a Yes/No answer to a query without using control flow functions(IIF,ELSE,CASE,COALESCE,ISNULL,IFNULL,etc). I want my query to give me a "Yes" answer if there has been a flight of a certain Airline on a given date between 2 given airports. This is what i have done so far

```
SELECT 'Yes' as Answer
FROM flights
WHERE flights.date = '2014-12-12' AND flights.routes_id IN (SELECT routes.id
                                                            FROM routes
                                                            INNER JOIN airlines
                                                            ON airlines.id = routes.airlines_id
                                                            WHERE airlines_id IN (SELECT airlines.id
                                                                                 FROM airlines
                                                                                 WHERE airlines.name='Olympic Airways')
                                                            AND routes.source_id = (SELECT airports.id
                                                                                    FROM airports
                                                                                    WHERE airports.name like '%Venizelos%')
                                                            AND routes.destination_id=(SELECT airports.id
                                                                                    FROM airports
                                                                                    WHERE airports.name like 'London Gatwick')) 
UNION
SELECT 'No' AS Answer
FROM flights
WHERE flights.date = '2014-12-12' AND flights.routes_id  NOT IN (SELECT routes.id
                                                                FROM routes
                                                                INNER JOIN airlines
                                                                ON airlines.id = routes.airlines_id
                                                                WHERE airlines_id IN (SELECT airlines.id
                                                                                    FROM airlines
                                                                                    WHERE airlines.name = 'Olympic Airways')
                                                                AND routes.source_id = (SELECT airports.id
                                                                                    FROM airports
                                                                                    WHERE airports.name like '%Venizelos%')
                                                                AND routes.destination_id=(SELECT airports.id
                                                                                    FROM airports
                                                                                    WHERE airports.name like 'London Gatwick'))
```

The problem is that when i run the queries it prints both Yes and No, when it should print only one of those two. 
How can it be fixed?

Comment: CASE is not a control flow function.  As an FYI, the tsql control flow language elements are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx

Comment: You are joining table `airlines` and then redundantly performing a subquery against that table.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Join `airlines` with which table?

Comment: @DataMasseur   
 
But here it says that CASE is a control flow function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: @CharisAlex, with `routes`, in your subqueries.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will try it and i'll let you know! Thanks for helping

Comment: @CharisAlex  Interesting.  I wonder why mySQL treats CASE differently than other RDBMS implementations.  In any case, sorry about that.  I thought I had clicked into a tsql question, although I use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in that day there will be flight for that airline, but also for others, from/to that airports but also from others.

Put your query inside another query like:

```
SELECT Max(Answer)
from (
      your query from the question
)
```

This will return `Yes` if you have at leas a good flight (because the internal query will return `Yes` and `No`) and `No` if you have only no matches (the results from the internal query will be only `No`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it does help, but when i run the first query alone with select flights.routes_id it returns one route. When i do it for the second one it returns 3 routes. Why doesn't max pick the max num of Answers? It may be dumb what i am asking but i am kinda baffled!

Comment: It returns the max for the Answer, it puts the values in alphabetical order, it doesn't care about the number of rows

Comment: So if the second query was first then it would have printed "No"?

Comment: Not really, Y will still come after N in the alphabet

Comment: Exactly, the order won't change anything